# Keyboard commands not working?

Tags: keyboard, mouse

So I've been trying to use Mouse.move();
and Keyboard.press();. Every time I try to send it to my Arduino(mega 2560) it says keyboard or mouse was not declared. Any solutions?

```
  #include <Keyboard.h>
void setup() {

  pinMode(2, INPUT);

  
}

void loop() {

  if (digitalRead(2) == HIGH) {
    Keyboard.begin();
    Keyboard.press(KEY_LEFT_ARROW);
  }
if(digitalRead(2)==LOW){
  Keyboard.end();
  
}
  
}
```

Comment: Yes, don't use a Mega2560. Instead use one of the boards the Keyboard and Mouse libraries are *designed* to work with. I.e., one that actually *has* a USB connection...!